# Stripe switch plan gives error : No subscription with sub_##### in stripe available

Tags: stripe-payments, .net-core-2.0

I am having a plan of $1600/month, now I want to switch all the users subscribed to this plan to a new plan of $1700/ month. But while switching the particular user I am getting this kind of exception.(No subscription with (sub_### i.e. my customer's subscription id) in stripe available) What could be the possible reason for this??. As when I open my stripe dashboard I have that particular customer with that subscriptionId. I have used the below code to switch the plan.

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("My key");
var service = new SubscriptionService();
Subscription subscription = service.Get(subscriptionId);
var items = new List<SubscriptionItemUpdateOption> {
    new SubscriptionItemUpdateOption {
        Id = subscriptionId,
        PlanId = planId,
    },
};
var options = new SubscriptionUpdateOptions {
    CancelAtPeriodEnd = false,
    Items = items,
};
subscription = service.Update(subscriptionId, options);
```

Comment: "No such..." errors usually happen when using the wrong API keys. Double check that the secret key in your code matches the one in your dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

Comment: @PaulAsjes   It do matches my stripe dashboard. As while switching of plans .Through my other code I create a new plan in stripe through API call. So the problem I get can be considered a valid point